# mongoose-paginate module is not supporting query operators

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-plugins

I just realised that mongoose-paginate IS NOT supporting Comparison Query Operators https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/

Example:

(`created_on: Date`)

```
Post.paginate({
    created_on: {
        gte: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')
    }
}, {
    page: 2,
    limit: 10,
    sort: {
        created_on: 'desc'
    }
}).then((data) => {
    // do something with docs
});
```

This will throw an error:

`CastError: Cast to date failed for value "{ gte: 2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z }" at path "created_on" for model "Post"`

It seems like it compares the property `created_on` with the whole object `{$gte: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')}` and it ignores that operator `$gte`.
In the example above, it tries to compare a date with an object which ends up thrown a cast error!

## UPDATE

Actually it was my mistake, forgot to put $ sign before `gte`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was my mistake that I forgot $ before `gte`

```
Post.paginate({
    created_on: {
        $gte: new Date('2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')
    }
}, {
    page: 2,
    limit: 10,
    sort: {
        created_on: 'desc'
    }
}).then((data) => {
    // do something with docs
});
```